# How can I find values for resistors and capacitors for an active bandpass filter with Rauch structure?

Tags: transfer-function, high-frequency, circuits

[image]

I have to find the values of the resistors and capacitors for this type of bandpass filter in order to obtain 105.5 MHz and 99,9MHz. I have found the transfer function, m, wc and the gain:

[image: H(jw)]

[image]

I am struggling to understand how to find the values necessary for such high frequencies as there are so many parameters.

Comment: Seriously consider using passive LCR filters at these frequencies instead. It'll be much easier with a much less exotic amplifier.

Comment: Please note that the structure you have chosen is known to have rather bad active sensitivities (against opamp non-idealities). For high frequencies there are other topologies with much better properties (less sensitive to the finite open-loop gain) , for example GIC-based structures (also known as Fliege-Filter).

Comment: @user_1818839 This is a school assignement, I must use an active bandpass filter

Comment: @Tassanix Ah good, then it doesn't have to work. As RF is usually 50 ohm terminated I suggest starting with R1 = 50 ohms and working everything else out from there. Expect C values in the 10s of picofarads.

Answer (score 1):

Its actually easier if you understand a few principles:

1. the corner frequency (for both low and high pass filters or \$ f_c = RC \$ is the same.
2. You can use super position to find the corner frequencies and seperate them.

So the first thing to do is identify the filter order, or how many poles and corner frequency it has. The next thing is determining low pass or high pass, a band pass needs two poles, one high and one low, each one will have a corner frequency.

So one corner frequency will be a high pass, which will be the lower frequency of 99MHz and the low pass will be the other corner frequency. Each one will have an RC pair and if no restrictions are given on the values, you can pick them: \$ f_c = RC \$ pick the capacitor and find R \$ (99MHz converted to radians) = R (1uF) \$

Comment: So by my calculations using C = 1F I have R = 628 mega ohm ( 99MHz is equal to approximately 628 000 000 rad/s) Does that mean R1 = R2 = R3 = 628M ohm ? I tried and it let the frequencies pass around 1,4MHz
Thanks for your help !

Comment: If you like the answer be sure to vote, use real values capacitors usually are in the uF range and resistors 10Meg to 0.1 Ohm for filters

Comment: Well how is it possible then ? I get 628*10^8 rad/s divided by 1*10^-6 which gives me 6,28*10^14 ohm which is definitely larger than 10M Ohm.